# Encoding a tab in html

Tags: html, html-entities

I can encode a space using `&nbsp;` in an HTML document. Is there an equivalent for the tab character?

I'm trying to preload a `<textarea>` with text that contains tabs, but my CMS removes any tab characters that exist in the HTML code.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

After reviewing your edit, the answer is very simply: `&#9;` :)

Comment: Not that simple actually. See my answer below

Comment: Actually, it was for the OP. He's using a `<textarea>`, which has similarities to `<pre>`. Your answer still has useful info, but you should add "`<textarea>` etc" after the word `<pre>` to acknowledge the original question.

Comment: No space allowed to encode in html, you mean &#9;:) ? xD

Answer (score 26):

**`&emsp;`**, **`&ensp;`**, **`&#8195;`** or **`&#8194;`** can be used.

[Read More at W3.org for HTML3](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/specialchars.html)

[Read More at W3.org for HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html)

Answer (score 10):

The only way to encode a TAB character in pure HTML is to surround it with `<pre></pre>` tags, which turns your font into a mono-space font like Courier New. There is no specific `<tab></tab>` like tags in HTML. Don't ask me why.

Place "`<textarea>` etc" in between the  tags.

With all due respect to the above answers, just placing `&#9` will not work as HTML will replace it with a space unless it's in-between the PRE tags.

Answer (score 8):

The simple and easy answer is including in CSS.

```css
white-space: pre;
```

Comment: This thing preserves both `\t` and `\n`. Perfect.